# $\sigma$-algebra vs. $\sigma$-field: is there any difference?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, terminology

The subject says it all: is there any difference between the two concepts of $\sigma$-algebra and $\sigma$-field? In probability theory, they seem to be used more or less interchangeably. If there is no difference, is there any historical reason why some people/schools use the term $\sigma$-algebra, while others use the term $\sigma-$field?

Comment: Alternate names for the same thing.  Each coming from a different part of mathematics.

Comment: @GEdgar Which parts?

Comment: In general, the term $\sigma$-algebra is used by people doing pure analysis, and the term $\sigma$-field is used by probability theorists. They are the same thing, however.

Comment: According to all I have read about this, they are the same thing, it is just that, for the name $\sigma$-field, it is more widely used when we are talking something related to probability theory.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to be completely sure you can see Taylor´s Introduction to Measure and Integration where he states that both concepts refer to the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

There is technically a difference between these two objects, but Stone's representation theorem says the two are isomorphic.

A boolean algebra is an abstract algebraic object.

> **Definition** A **Boolean algebra** is a non-empty set $A$, together with two binary operations $\wedge$ and $\vee$ (on $A$ ), a unary operation $'$, and two distinguished elements 0 and 1 , satisfying the following axioms,
> $$
> \begin{array}{rlrl}
> 0^{\prime}  =1, & 1^{\prime}  =0,& & (p \wedge q)^{\prime}=p^{\prime} \vee q^{\prime},  \\
> p \wedge 0  =0, & p \vee 1  =1, && p \wedge q=q \wedge p,  \\
> p \wedge 1  =p, & p \vee 0  =p, &&  p \wedge(q \wedge r)=(p \wedge q) \wedge r, \\
> p \wedge p^{\prime}  =0, & p \vee p^{\prime}  =1, && (p \vee q)^{\prime}=p^{\prime} \wedge q^{\prime},\\
> p \wedge p  =p, &\left(p^{\prime}\right)^{\prime}=p  && (p \vee q)^{\prime}=p^{\prime} \wedge q^{\prime}, \\
> p \vee p  =p &&& p \vee q=q \vee p\\
> &&& p \vee q=q \vee p, \\
> &&& p \wedge(q \vee r)=(p \wedge q) \vee(p \wedge r), \\
> &&& p \vee(q \vee r)=(p \vee q) \vee r, \\
> &&& p \vee(q \wedge r)=(p \vee q) \wedge(p \vee r) . \\
> \end{array}
> $$

A field of set is a narrower example of a boolean algebra.

> **Definition** A **field of sets** is a pair $(X, \mathcal{F})$ consisting of a set $X$ and a family $\mathcal{F}$ of subsets of $X$ called an algebra over $X$ that contains the empty set as an element, and is closed under the operations of taking complements in $X$, finite unions, and finite intersections.

The reason that there is no distinction made between them in measure theory texts, is due to Stone's representation theorem for boolean algebras which essentially says that every boolean algebra is isomorphic to some field of sets. This can be found in [Halmos's Introduction to Boolean Algebras](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-68436-9), and the specific corollary answering the question is found on page 381

> **Corollary 1.** Every  $\sigma$-algebra is isomorphic to some $\sigma$-field modulo a $\sigma$-ideal.