# Why is the standard notation to denote a $\sigma$-algebra the letter $\mathcal{F}$?

Tags: measure-theory, notation, soft-question

This question is probably silly, but notation is important for one's subconcious.

Lately I've been learning about probability theory and in many books and papers (even the one where Kolmogorov introduced the notion of a probability space in 1933) whenever there's a $\sigma$-algebra it's almost always called one of two ways $\mathcal{F}$ or $\mathcal{B}$.

I assume the second one is because of Borel, but I do not get why the letter of choice is an $\mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Maybe we have to check on original source (1933); the English translation (1959) has $\mathfrak F$ and call it *a field of sets*.

Comment: But it seems that also the [original German](https://www.google.it/books/edition/Grundbegriffe_der_Wahrscheinlichkeitsrec/KeObBgAAQBAJ) has $\mathfrak F$ for [Mengenkörper](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6rper_(Algebra)).

Comment: In Probability Theory, it is rather common to call "field" (resp. "$\sigma$-field") to what is called "algebra" (resp. "$\sigma$-algebra") in Analysis.  

See:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2192781/sigma-algebra-vs-sigma-field-is-there-any-difference